# mogrify -resize and append new filesize to filename

Tags: imagemagick, command-line-interface

I would like to `mogrify -resize 500` my files and append the new filesize to the filename ie: image-500*500.png

Can someone help me out please.

Comment: What version of Imagemagick are you using as it could probably be done easier in version 7

Comment: @Bonzo im using the latest version just installed via homebrew

Comment: I assume homebrew is a mac program and that you are using a version 6. In that case I suggest you write some code using identify to get the image name into a variable and then use that variable in a convert command. Looping through all the images with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do that with `mogrify` because it overwrites the original filename rather than creating a new one. So, I think you will need to do it with `convert`.

So, for one file called `input.png`:

```
convert input.png -resize 400x500\! -set filename:f "%[t]-%[w]x%[h]" "%[filename:f].png"
```

and your output file will be `input-400x500.png`

If you wanted to do a whole directory full of PNG files on a Mac, you would **make a backup and, then on a spare copy** do:

```
for f in *.png; do
   convert "$f" -resize 400x500\! -set filename:f "%[t]-%[w]x%[h]" "%[filename:f].png"
done
```